# get $index of item within ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">
<li>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

js

```
$scope.item = [
{
    "itemId": 1,
    "name":"laptop"
}
];
```

I want to the $index of item to be my itemId so in the future I can store in db or use it in somewhere else. I can do `<li>{{$index}}</li>` but how to bind it with my object of item in js?

Comment: Index is just the array index iirc you more likely want to use `{{itemId}}` within the scope of the each item.

Comment: so you're saying just set a fixed itemId like 1 in the object then if any new item coming in I do like "itemId" : 1+1? instead of using $index?

Comment: [index is just a counter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind with

```
<li ng-bind="$inndex" ></li>
```

Or store in id or other tags by

```
<li custom_tag="{{$index}}"></li>
```

Comment: how would this help me to access the index in js side?

Comment: its depend how you want to use, If you want to use inside the controller then no need to store as this index is array index. You can get same index by looping in js side

** same scope

Answer (score 0):

One trick for selection of individual items of `ng-repeat`, is the inclusion of an `controller` in the same element as the ng-repeat.

The ng-repeat dedicated controller will contain all the new items generated by the iteration, ng-click calling a function in that controller will do the item selection.

Check Demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kA0BYw?p=preview).

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in invoices" 
         ng-controller="RowCtrl" 
         ng-click="toggleRow()" 
         ng-switch on="isSelected()">
    <tr>
        <td>{{i.name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.company}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-switch-when="true">
        <td>{{i.invoice}}</td>
        <td>{{i.units}}</td>
    </tr>
```